# CustomServiceHostFactory and Generating proxies in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf

Hi I'm using and Custom ServiceHostFactory, and when I want to update service reference it would'nt work because I assume it needs to setup my servicehostfactory and it will crash.

I have looked for other approaches to not use the generation, but I havent found any good replacements.

Are there anyway to go around this, to not remove the servicehostfactory from the svc files everytime and then put them back there after service reference updates :S.

Comment: Solved it, had an error in my namespace

Answer (score 0):

We use the non generation method described in [this](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122) dnrtv screencast.

It has worked very well for us. Prevoiously we wasted alot of time due to references not updating or developers forgetting to update a reference before they checked in code.

Comment: Yeah I have used it in some wpf to wcf services and it works great, but in Silverlight you need to implement 3 methods in both interface, proxy and service class, it feels a little overkill :|.

Answer (score 0):

I rechecked the namespace path and it were wrong in the svc file.